# Raspberry Pi firebase-admin error

Tags: data-transfer, database

I want to send the data I read from the distance sensor with Raspberry Pi to the firebase realtime database. When I set up a virtual environment (venv), I can provide any data sending function. However, when I use the gpiozero library while the virtual environment is running, it gives an error. When I deactivate the virtual environment, it says firebase_admin library could not be found. It does not allow pip install without a virtual environment. How can I solve the problem?

distance.py

```
    from gpiozero import DistanceSensor
    from time import sleep
    from myfirebase import send_data
    
    # Mesafe sensörünü tanımla
    sensor = DistanceSensor(echo=27, trigger=17)
    
    try:
        while True:
            mesafe = sensor.distance * 100  # Metre cinsinden mesafeyi santimetre cinsine çevir
            print("Mesafe: {:.2f} cm".format(mesafe))
            send_data(mesafe)
            if(mesafe < 20):
                print("you cannot go")
            sleep(1)
            
    
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        # Ctrl+C ile programı kapat
        pass
    
    finally:
        # GPIO pinlerini temizle
        sensor.close()
```

myfirebase.py

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, db
import time

# Firebase Config bilgilerini ekleyin
cred = credentials.Certificate("/home/pi/Desktop/test/fireeeee.........json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://fireeeee-......./'
})

# Veri gönderme örneği
def send_data(data):

    ref = db.reference('distance')
    ref.set(data)

# Veri alma örneği
def receive_data():
    ref = db.reference('distance')
    data = ref.get()
    print("Received Data:", data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Test için veri gönderme
    #send_data({"temperature": 25, "humidity": 60})

    # Bekleme süresi
    time.sleep(2)

    # Test için veri alma
    receive_data()
```

Note:

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely how you setup your virtual environment (which you haven't explained - neither have you listed the actual error message).
If you setup to allow access to system-site-packages it should work.

Example (setting up in directory cp):-
`mkdir cp && cd cp && python -m venv --system-site-packages env`